# Restoring Derby-Database via Java

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, restore

I'm trying to restore an Apache Derby Database via Java. While researching I found the following page http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/adminguide/tadminhubbkup44.html . As far as I understand I got to have a running connection to the server and use the given URL to make a restore happen.

I'm not sure how to restart and restore the running server in Java using this URL.

Comment: What aren't you sure about? You seem to have found the docs, and you seem to understand what they say. The only thing left is to write a Java JDBC program which calls DriverManager.getConnection() with the appropriate URL. Make sure to test your program with a test database, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to restore the derby database using the backup files created. The problem was that I needed to shut down the database before trying to restore it.

But now I ran into another problem. After the shutdown and the following restore of the database the database doesn't boot automatically. I have tried to register a new driver or to set the shutdown attribute to false but none of that has worked to reboot the database via Java.

This is my code so far:

```
public boolean restore() throws DataSourceException {  
  String databaseName = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples;restoreFrom="+ getRestorePath() +"sun-appserv-samples";
  String delete = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples;shutdown=true";
  try {
   DriverManager.getConnection(delete);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   Connection con;
   try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseName);
    con.commit();  
    try {                  
     Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
    }

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples;create=true");
    con.commit();
    return true;
   } catch (SQLException e1) {
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
```